# Build fails on Xcode for simple, automatically generated "Hello World" program

Tags: xcode

I just started with Xcode, but got problem building even the auto-generated "Hello World" program.The errors are as follows:
[image]

I want to know what could possibly be the reason for this.Thank you.

Comment: Your picture is cutting off the error message.  What is the full text of the "Unable to write to file..." lines?

Comment: @PhillipMills Sorry I was using computers at the uni, therefore I'm unable to  confirm that right now. I will update this question tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: When you do that, you might want to check that you have correct permissions to write into whatever directory it specifies in the full error.